# Resource not found exception for selector.xml

Tags: android

I am having a problem where I am getting this error...

> 03-02 19:59:03.539: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.comp4020.kitchenaid/com.kitchenaid.MainActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/main_button.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020003

I have no clue why this is happening. The resource most definitely exists and it named properly with no errors. The only think I can think of is that I added chars to the program there were not in default character set so it asked "Change to UTF-8" and I said yes.

I am assigning this resource as follows...

```
ingButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_button);
nextButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_button);
prevButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_button);
timerButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_button);
```

I also tried cleaning project. I have no clue what is going on.

EDIT: Here is the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_pressed"
        />
     <item android:background="@drawable/gradient"/>

</selector>
```

gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/gradientDark" 
              android:centerColor="@color/gradientDark"
              android:endColor="@color/gradientLight" 
              android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

gradient_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/highlightGradientDark" 
              android:centerColor="@color/highlightGradientDark"
              android:endColor="@color/highlightGradientLight" 
              android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: Can you confirm and post your main_button.xml file

Comment: Just wanted to check if these drawables maybe are different sizes and some of them aren't there? ie: you are loading some stuff for a tablet?

Comment: did you assigned your gradient ad gradient_pressed in your main Activity?

Comment: Yes they are assigned in main activity.

Comment: Just curious, confirm that the id ( #0x7f020003 ) corresponds to the expected resource in your R.txt file.

Answer (score 2):

New versions of Android explains with a little bit more of detail:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5591): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML
file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

The problem is that the selector has **android:color** or in your case **android:background** in each item instead of **android:drawable**, changing to the former one solves the issue.

Comment: What do you mean changing to the former? What is former? Very vague explanation.

Comment: @ulusoyca I am sorry that your English is not good, the former refers to the "latter", in the sentence that means that changing `android:background` to `android:drawable` should solve the issue